# Как правильно пишется "асинхронный", одно "с" или два "сс"?

Tags: орфография

Курс будет проходить в ассинхронном формате.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Почему снова не голосуете за понравившийся ответ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Курс будет проходить в а**с**инхронном формате.*

**[Словарь Грамоты](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&mode=slovari&dicts%5B%5D=71&dicts%5B%5D=49&dicts%5B%5D=47&dicts%5B%5D=27&dicts%5B%5D=24&dicts%5B%5D=42&dicts%5B%5D=9&dicts%5B%5D=50&dicts%5B%5D=52&dicts%5B%5D=30&dicts%5B%5D=29&dicts%5B%5D=48&dicts%5B%5D=26&dicts%5B%5D=28&dicts%5B%5D=25)**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]